How to Enable Connected App Device Flow via API?
Is there a way to deploy a connected app with the Device Flow enabled? Alternatively, can an existing connected app be updated to enable the Device Flow using an API?

Welcome to the exchange! Can you add a bit more detail to your question? What have you tried, what trouble are you experiencing with deploying? What tools are you using? Providing the steps to reproduce is helpful as well. Anything you can do to add more context will better the likeliness of your question being answered. Thanks for the help!
